# how to create one controller and multiple view in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm using ASP.NET MVC5 with Entity Framework 4.5 and want to create multiple views in a single controller. Suppose I have MasterController in that i want action like add edit and display methods
and in view folder i have a folder name "Masters" in this folder i want category wise folder and in folder cshtml file.
i am sharing structure in image for what i want.
is this possible?

> here is my view structure

[image]

> here is my controller structure

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can simply create a new controller in `ASP.NET MVC` project and decorate it like this with the following action methods:

**`MasterController.cs`**

```
    public class MasterController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddCurrency(int? id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CurrencyDetails()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public ActionResult DeleteDetail(int? id)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Afterwards, go to each of these action methods, right click to Add View and click Ok. By default, all views related to a controller gets created in `Views/<FolderWithControllerName>` such as `Views/Master`.
Create folders manually in it and drag and drop the views accordingly.

[image]

Since, you are overriding the default conventions, you need to explicitly mention the path to your views while calling them from action methods. Modify the controller like it and you are good to go:

```
    public class MasterController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddCurrency(int? id)
        {
            //return View();
            return View("/Views/Master/AddCurrency/AddCurrency.cshtml");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CurrencyDetails()
        {
            //return View();
            return View("/Views/Master/CurrencyDetails/CurrencyDetails.cshtml");
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public ActionResult DeleteDetail(int? id)
        {
            //return View();
            return View("/Views/Master/DeleteDetail/DeleteDetail.cshtml");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.You should return view in controller action as this.

```
return View("~/Views/FolderName/ViewName.cshtml");
```